# Overwrite controller from vendors

Tags: php, symfony, admin-generator

i`m have bundle in my project vendors. Necessary overwrite EditController class. My vendor bundle build with help CedricLambardot AdminGeneratorBundle. I overwrite *-generator.yml and pointed params.bundle_name name my vendor bundle. Owerrite controller too, but him dont work, all the same symfony using controller from vendor.

EditController.php from vendor:

```
namespace Acme\ProductBundle\Controller\Product;

use Admingenerated\AcmeProductBundle\BaseProductController\EditController as BaseEditController;
// ...

class EditController extends BaseEditController
{
    // ...
}
```

Overwrited EditController.php

```
namespace Acme\AnniProductBundle\Controller\Product;

use Acme\ProductBundle\Controller\Product\EditController as BaseEditController;
// ...

class EditController extends BaseEditController
{
    // ...
}
```

My overwrited *-generator.yml:

```
generator: admingenerator.generator.doctrine_odm
params:
  model: Acme\AnniProductBundle\Document\Product
  namespace_prefix: Acme
  bundle_name: ProductBundle
  object_actions:
        delete: ~
  fields:
    name:
      label: Name
    # ...
  # ...
```

My routes:

```
Acme_ProductBundle_Product_list:
    path:      /product/
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeAnniProductBundle:Product\List:index }

Acme_ProductBundle_Product_filters:
    path:      /product/filter
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeAnniProductBundle:Product\List:filter }

Acme_ProductBundle_Product_edit:
    path:      /product/{pk}/edit
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeAnniProductBundle:Product\Edit:index }

Acme_ProductBundle_Product_update:
    path:      /product/{pk}/update
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeAnniProductBundle:Product\Edit:update }

Acme_ProductBundle_Product_object:
    path:      /product/{pk}/{action}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeAnniProductBundle:Product\Actions:object }

Acme_ProductBundle_Product_new:
    path:      /product/new
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeAnniProductBundle:Product\New:index }

Acme_ProductBundle_Product_create:
    path:      /product/create
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeAnniProductBundle:Product\New:create }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with annotation:

Parent controller:

```
namespace Acme\ProductBundle\Controller\Product;

use Admingenerated\AcmeProductBundle\BaseProductController\EditController as     BaseEditController;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;
// ...

class EditController extends BaseEditController
{
    /** @DI\Inject("doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager") */
    private $dm;

    // ...
}
```

If in overwriten controller write:

```
/** @DI\Inject("doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager") */
private $dm;
```

All works

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options.

1. Check where the routes are set.  Probably in a routes.yml file somewhere.  Adjust the routes to point to your controllers.
2. If step 1 is not feasible then try bundle inheritance: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

If neither of these approaches work then we will probably need some more details.  Might also check the bundle documentation for hints.  It's also possible that the controllers might be sending out events which in turn might mean you don't have to override them at all.

Comment: I overwrite all routes, but all the same using old controller

Comment: You need to point the route to your controller.  Please update your question with one of your overridden routes if you think you have.  Remember that the last route loaded will override previous routes so order might be important.  You might want to use app/console route:debug to check.  Tweak the method to verify your changes have stick.

Comment: I'm guessing that they are either not being or they are being loaded before the standard routes.  In app/config/routes.yml are all your resource lines coming before your routes?

Comment: all routes is right. if i dont pointed routes, symfony show error that route can not be found...

Comment: It's not a question of the route being found, it's a question of the RIGHT route being found.  If you have defined two routes with the same name in two different files then the last one loaded is used.  Hence the questions about the route file load order.  Consider adding app/config/routes.yml to your question.

Comment: run: app/console router:debug Acme_ProductBundle_Product_edit and see what it says about the controller.   app/console router:match /product/edit might also be handy.  Or have you already tried these?

Comment: route:debug Acme_ProductBundle_Product_edit - give right controller, and router:match /en/product/edit - give right controller. But my owerwriten controller not using.

Comment: If I remove the class inheritance BaseListController in my new ListController that uses a new, redefined controller. And if leave the inheritance, it is not used.

Comment: If I put 
use Admingenerated\AcmeProductBundle\BaseProductController\ListController as BaseListController;

class ListController extends BaseListController
{
    // ...
}

That all works fine.